# How to enable 'scan new card' option for Google chrome in android?

Tags: android, google-chrome

Google chrome has this functionality for scanning credit card to populate the fields during payment which works in Android Chrome ( not for all versions and devices of android ).

I have attached the screenshot.

It shows on other websites, but not in my website. Do we have any references to what should be the content of html dom for it to work?[image]

Comment: I am late to the party ! I have tried the same website but did't get scan option. Can you please specify android and chrome version on which this implementation can be verified ?

Comment: Check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values) from Goolge developers

Comment: I am able to get this option in Android OS 9 but in Android OS 10 i didn't get any option to Scan in google chrome. Can anyone help me with this? I have also posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112991/android-10-scan-new-card-not-working-in-google-chrome

Comment: issue facing on card scan. Can anyone help me with this? I have also posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409307/cam-card-scanner-auto-fill-is-not-happening

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/#payment-fields-are-completely-wonky) the payment fields are completely wonky.
In order to build a cross browser autofill form with credit card scan feature (if browser supports it) you need:

1. Add autocomplete attributes
2. Use common values for input name attributes
3. Add name and/or label values that match the list Safari is looking for
4. Use HTTPS with valid certificate

Here is [the final form to test](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/#the-final-form).