# Credit card scan in google chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Does anybody know if latest Google Chrome browsers support scanning credit card data using mobile device camera? I've tried using suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194966/how-to-enable-scan-new-card-option-for-google-chrome-in-android) link, but couldn't manage to get it working on any device.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that scanning credit card option was moved to application associated with payments - GPay. But my region doesn't support GPay, so I doesn't have this app installed and can't scan card from chrome.

Comment: Hi, did you find any official document or article which says that feature has been moved to G-Pay and no longer by "scan by camera"?

Comment: I have observed that in some android devices Scan new card option(i.e.Realme, Vivo etc.) is visible but in other devices(i.e. Motorola) this option is not visible though the version of google chrome and android OS is same in all devices. I have verified with android OS 10 and 11.