# Android 10: Scan new card not working in Google chrome

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am integrating html page in webview and in that i need to scan the credit card.
But, in my android device version 10, "Scan new card" option is not visible.
In android 8, this option is visible but Card holder name is not coming.
So anyone have any idea about the same?
Below is the activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    // REMOTE RESOURCE
     mWebView.loadUrl("https://hostedhtml/");
}
```

Below is the html code:

```
<form action="freedomofkeima://?ThisIsResponseSample" method="get">
            <label for="nameoncard">Name on Card</label> 
            <input autocomplete="cc-name" id="nameoncard" name="nameoncard" type="text"> 
            <label for="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</label> 
            <input autocomplete="cc-number" id="ccnumber" name="ccnumber" type="text">
            <label for="cc-exp-month">Expiration Month</label> 
            <input autocomplete="cc-exp-month" id="cc-exp-month" name="cc-exp-month" type="text"> 
            <label for="cc-exp-year">Expiration Year</label> 
            <input autocomplete="cc-exp-year" id="cc-exp-year" name="cc-exp-year" type="text"> 
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

MyWebClient code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String hostname;

    // YOUR HOSTNAME
    hostname = "example.com";

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (url.startsWith("file:") || uri.getHost() != null && uri.getHost().endsWith(hostname)) {
        return false;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you show some code? maybe you have to enable JS and DOM storage?

Comment: @snachmsm I have added activity and html code.

Comment: try to add `webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`, I don't have any other clues... besides that you should also show `MyWebViewClient` source, as `WebViewClient` can intercept some web-calls (e.g. JS execution/lib load)

Comment: @snachmsm I have added mywebclient code.