# cam card scanner auto fill is not happening

Tags: javascript, android, html, autofill

my input field is created like this :`<input type="tel" id="card-number" name="account_number" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="Card Number" maxlength="23" class="form-control cardNumber" data-rule-required="false">`

once click the scan new card, card number is scanning properly. But, if i enter 1 digit the auto fill is not working.[image]